# subprocess.check_output() : bash command not found when setting parm executable='/bin/bash'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I'm running Python 3.6 on an Centos box.

Here's my non-working code

```
shell_command = subprocess.check_output(["ll"],shell=True, universal_newlines=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Here's the output:

```
/bin/bash: ll: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./snmp_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    shell_command = subprocess.check_output(["ll"],shell=True, universal_newlines=True, executable='/bin/bash')
  File "/data/prod_envs/pythons/python36/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/data/prod_envs/pythons/python36/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ll']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

So judging by the error

```
/bin/bash: ll: command not found
```

bash doesnt know `ll`

which is weird, because `echo "$SHELL"` returns

```
/bin/bash
```

and via CLI, the `ll` command works.

I can't figure out what the issue is. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: yes
ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'
I changed the code to

Comment: Two problems: 1) if you are using `shell=True`, don't provide a list; just use `check_output("ll", ...)`. 2) `ll` is likely an *alias* that isn't defined in the *noninteractive* shell that is being started. It's probably best to spell out the command you *expect* `ll` to expand to, rather than trying to make sure the alias is defined properly in the first place.

Comment: changed that line to 
```
shell_command = subprocess.check_output(["ls -l --color=auto"],shell=True, universal_newlines=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```
and now it works like a charm (feeling kinda stupid now :-)  ) thanks for your help

Comment: Using a list and `shell=True` generally means the same thing as using a list `['sh', '-c'] + your_list and `shell=False`. If `your_list` has more than one element, it's probably not doing what you expect.

Comment: Don't bother using the shell at all here; see my answer.

Comment: Btw, use single-backticks to format code inline. Triple-backticks are for code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on aliases from your personal shell configuration being defined; spell out the command you expect it to resolve to.

```
shell_command = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "--color=auto"], universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: YES, that looks much better. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score -1):

found out that 'll' was an alias , and changed the line of code to

```
shell_command = subprocess.check_output("ls -l --color=auto",shell=True, universal_newlines=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

and now it works like a charm.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` unless you really need the shell to do something. You can execute `ls` without shell intervention.